# Bookmarklet works correctly when pasted into console but not when the bookmark is clicked

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have the below script which works as expected if the code is pasted into and run directly from the console. However, if I take the exact same code and minify it onto one line myself, running that one line via a bookmark returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. I've also tried minifying using [bookmarkleter](http://jpillora.com/bookmarkleter), but that returns the same error. How do I fix this error and get the script to run correctly as a bookmarklet?

Original code:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var thisUser = Waze.loginManager.user;
    if (thisUser === null) return;
    var usrRank = thisUser.normalizedLevel;
    var UpdateObject;
    if (typeof(require) !== "undefined") {
        UpdateObject = require("Waze/Action/UpdateObject");
    } else {
        UpdateObject = Waze.Action.UpdateObject;
    }

    function onScreen(obj) {
        if (obj.geometry) {
            return (W.map.getExtent().intersectsBounds(obj.geometry.getBounds()));
        }
        return (false);
    }

    Object.forEach(W.model.segments.objects, function(k, v) {
        if (onScreen(v) && v.isGeometryEditable() && v.attributes.roadType === 3 && v.attributes.lockRank <= usrRank) {
            count++;
            W.model.actionManager.add(new UpdateObject(v, {
                lockRank: 0
            }))
        }
    })

    alert(count + " segments were updated.");
})();
```

Manually minified:

```
javascript:(function(){var count = 0;var thisUser = Waze.loginManager.user;if(thisUser === null)return;var usrRank = thisUser.normalizedLevel;var UpdateObject;if(typeof(require)!=="undefined"){UpdateObject=require("Waze/Action/UpdateObject");}else{UpdateObject=Waze.Action.UpdateObject;}function onScreen(obj){if(obj.geometry){return(W.map.getExtent().intersectsBounds(obj.geometry.getBounds()));}return(false);}Object.forEach(W.model.segments.objects,function(k, v){if(onScreen(v)&&v.isGeometryEditable()&&v.attributes.roadType===3&&v.attributes.lockRank<==usrRank){count++;W.model.actionManager.add(new UpdateObject(v,{lockRank: 0}))}})alert(count+" segments were updated.");})();
```

Minified with [bookmarkleter](http://jpillora.com/bookmarkleter):

```
javascript:(function(){var%20count=0;var%20thisUser=Waze.loginManager.user;if(thisUser===null)return;var%20usrRank=thisUser.normalizedLevel;var%20UpdateObject;if(typeof(require)!==%22undefined%22){UpdateObject=require(%22Waze/Action/UpdateObject%22);}else{UpdateObject=Waze.Action.UpdateObject;}function%20onScreen(obj){if(obj.geometry){return(W.map.getExtent().intersectsBounds(obj.geometry.getBounds()));}return(false);}Object.forEach(W.model.segments.objects,function(k,v){if(onScreen(v)%26%26%20v.isGeometryEditable()%26%26%20v.attributes.roadType===3%20%26%26%20v.attributes.lockRank%20%3C=usrRank){count++;W.model.actionManager.add(new%20UpdateObject(v,{lockRank:0}))}})alert(count+%22%20segments%20were%20updated.%22);})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing semicolon

```
})alert(cou
^^^
```

Always use semicolons! Your pretty formatted version is missing a few.

Comment: Ugh, I'll be honest, I'm never sure where semicolons are supposed to go; I didn't realize I needed one after that `forEach`. I added this one and it works now, thank you!

Comment: Tools like JSLInt or JSHint can help out